# Trouble with variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, counting

I'm new to javascript and am having trouble with a counting program and I believe it could be trouble with variable scope.

```
var count = 0; {
    function gimmeRandom() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        count++;
    }

    function countToRandom() {
        for (count = 1; count <= rand; count++) {
            console.log(count);
        }
    }

    console.log("Counting to a random number");
    gimmeRandom();
    countToRandom();
    console.log("Counting to another random number");
    gimmeRandom();
    countToRandom();
    console.log("There has been " + count + " random numbers used");
}
```

Comment: There is an opening bracket at line 2, sure this is not a typo?

Comment: What goes wrong? What do you expect, and how do the results differ? *edit* and yes the code as posted is syntactically incorrect, so it's hard to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `var rand` inside `gimmeRandom`, you can't  access it in `countToRandom`. You probably want a global variable, just as you did with `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring var inside of a function scopes that variable to the function. You have two choices.

1. Since you are calling gimmeRandom first, drop the var keyword and it will be automatically global.

```js
var count = 0;     

{                                               
function gimmeRandom()                                              
{                                               
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;                                                
  count++;                                              
}                                               

function countToRandom()                                                
{                                               
  for (count = 1; count <= rand; count++)                                               
  {                                             
     console.log(count);                                                
  }                                             
}                                               

console.log("Counting to a random number");                                             
gimmeRandom();                                              
countToRandom();                                                
console.log("Counting to another random number");                                               
gimmeRandom();                                              
countToRandom();                                                
console.log("There has been "+count+" random numbers used");                                                
}
```

2. Define var rand at the top of the page to make it global.

```js
var count = 0;     
var rand = 0;

{                                               
function gimmeRandom()                                              
{                                               
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;                                                
  count++;                                              
}                                               

function countToRandom()                                                
{                                               
  for (count = 1; count <= rand; count++)                                               
  {                                             
     console.log(count);                                                
  }                                             
}                                               

console.log("Counting to a random number");                                             
gimmeRandom();                                              
countToRandom();                                                
console.log("Counting to another random number");                                               
gimmeRandom();                                              
countToRandom();                                                
console.log("There has been "+count+" random numbers used");                                                
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I needed  but the the count variable isn't working properly. I think it's to do with the last line of code but I'm not too sure

Comment: @jonnyc132 what is count supposed to do? Right now it is doing exactly what you are telling it to do...

Comment: ideally I'd want it to show how many random numbers there have been, or how many times gimmeRandom has been called

Answer (score 0):

You define rand to be bounded in this function:

```
    function gimmeRandom() {
         var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
         count++;
    }
```

And then try to use it in another function:

```
    function countToRandom() {
        for (count = 1; count <= rand; count++) {
            console.log(count);
        }
    }
```

As seen in this question:

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Your variable `rand` you define is given a local scope to the gimmeRandom() function and therefore can't be used outside that function.

To use it across functions you'd probably wan to make the variable have global scope